# Concordion can not copy resource (all of a sudden)

Tags: concordion

Bit strange but all of a sudden (as in, my acceptance test suite was running fine and I'm busy doing some unrelated* unit tests) when I start to get failures copying resources on a test run.

```
Failed to copy /org/demo/foo/../../../concordion.css to target [Resource: /org/demo/foo/../../../concordion.css]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to copy /org/demo/foo/../../../concordion.css to target [Resource: /org/demo/foo/../../../concordion.css]
    at org.concordion.internal.ConcordionBuilder.copyResources(ConcordionBuilder.java:354)
    at org.concordion.internal.ConcordionBuilder.build(ConcordionBuilder.java:307)
    at org.concordion.internal.FixtureRunner.<init>(FixtureRunner.java:21)
    at org.concordion.integration.junit4.ConcordionRunner.<init>(ConcordionRunner.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/folders/wg/3nnv2yf90914pqpx69wmd9cc0000gn/T/concordion/org/demo/foo/../../../concordion.css (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at org.concordion.internal.FileTarget.createOutputStream(FileTarget.java:72)
    at org.concordion.internal.FileTarget.copyTo(FileTarget.java:35)
    at org.concordion.internal.ConcordionBuilder.copyResources(ConcordionBuilder.java:352)
    ... 43 more
```

I get this in IntelliJ IDEA and terminal running gradle.

My tests all start with something similar to this:

```java
@RunWith(ConcordionRunner.class)
@ConcordionResources(value = { "../../../concordion.css" })
public class Index {
}
```

...and the `.css` file is where it always was (in the source tree). I checked for open handles and cleaned everything before rebuilding. Folder permissions seem fine. The `/var` folder in question is indeed empty.

Any ideas?

*I think

**UPDATE**: On Mac and Linux, if you delete the `/var/folders/../concordion` or `/tmp/concordion` (respectively), it will reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Concordion's `FileTarget#createOutputStream(Resource)` method is unable to create an `OutputStream` to write the resource.

Assuming your fixture is in the `a.b.c` package, Concordion is trying to create an `OutputStream` for the file `"<concordion.output.dir>/a/b/c/../../../concordion.css"` (where `<concordion.output.dir>` is the concordion output directory). If the `"<concordion.output.dir>/a/b/c/"` folder does not already exist this fails - it seems that Java does not automatically "normalize" the path to remove "`..`"s.

The solution will be to normalize the path (probably using `Path.normalize()`).

To resolve, you can either update to the 2.2.1 release which should be available soon, or use absolute paths (eg. `@ConcordionResources("/concordion.css")`).

Comment: Sorry, the release will take longer and won't just be a patch release - we're going to need to update to Java 7 for Path.normalize(). I've raised this issue at https://github.com/concordion/concordion/issues/286.

Comment: Thanks Nigel, I came to the same conclusion RE the ellipses. The hint for me what that plain old `ls` in the terminal reproduced the error! I got round it for now but just using `/concordion.css` in the fixture code (but aren't sure that's the best approach). Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered filename or directory capitalisation? Linux is is strict whereas Mac is odd with filename capitalisation.

Tim

Comment: More of a comment than an answer - delete this answer and you'll be able to comment.